# Appcelerator run app on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone, appcelerator

I have this problem when build app on windows platform on device or emulator, `appcelerator` gives me this message:

> [ERROR] :  Invalid "--device-id" value "8-1-1"
>   2016-02-15T16:10:38.129Z | TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 1
>   2016-02-15T16:10:38.129Z | ERROR  | Error: ti run exited with error code 1
>       at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\AAFGROUP.appcelerator\install\5.1.0\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium\plugins\run.js:92:23)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
>   2016-02-15T16:10:38.129Z | TRACE  |
>   Sending exit signal to titanium process:  4972

I have already installed :

- visual studio 2015
- windows phone sdk
- subscribe developer microsoft
- configure appacelerator studio with publish id

Answer (score 0):

Open the Command Prompt (or PowerShell) and run `ti info` and see if Titanium finds your Visual Studio installation and Windows Phone SDK. Also check the "issues" at the end for any other potential problems.

Titanium searches the Windows Registry for the installation location and it's possible that the Visual Studio or Windows Phone SDK installation is incomplete or corrupt.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris, we fix the problem to re-install visual studio 2015 community.

Comment: Awesome! Good luck with your app!